# How can I get jars compatiple with Spark SQL 3.2.1 for Java 1.8

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, jar

My java 1.8 program tries to use MariaDB and Spark SQL 3.2.1 binaries

Compiled and run as follows

```
export CLASSPATH=./hadoop-common-3.3.1.jar:/usr/share/java/slf4j-nop.jar:/mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar:./spark-network-common_2.12-3.2.1.jar:-/spark-catalyst_2.12-3.2.1.jar:./spark-core_2.12-3.2.1.jar:./spark-sql_2.12-3.2.1.jar:./spark-hive_2.12-3.2.1.jar:$CLASSPATH
javac ordersETL.java
java ordersETL
```

Failing on:
SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("ETL experiment").master("local").getOrCreate();
as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Product.$init$(Lscala/Product;)V
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.<init>(SparkConf.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<init>(SparkConf.scala:596)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.<clinit>(SparkConf.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)
    at   org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$1(SparkSession.scala:920)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:230)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:920)
    at ordersETL.main(ordersETL.java:102)
```

The jar files I have downloaded from Maven Repository
assuming that "2.12-3.2.1" jars are compiled by Scala 2.12 for Spark SQL 3.2.1
but googling on the error message I've multiple matches saying that I should
get back to jars compiled by Scala 2.11.
However, there ain't 2.11-3.2.1 jars in Maven repository.
My question is: How can I get jars compatible with Spark SQL 3.2.1?